# Javascript for popup image not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the link for my site.http://vani.valse.com.my/schone_lightings/productdetail.php

The thumbnail when clicked must pop up but its not working.I've included all the files needed yet can't figure out what's missing.

I created a test page and just included the image.But it's working here.
http://vani.valse.com.my/schone_lightings/test.php

In header

```
 <!--only for productdetail.php starts-->

<!-- Carousel -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/jcarousel/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/jcarousel/css/product/skin.css" />
<!-- ColorBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/colorbox/colorbox.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/lib/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel();

    $(".thumb_button").hover(function() {
      var str = '<img src=\''+$(this).attr("image-cover")+'\' class=\'cover\' />';
      $("#image_box").html(str);
    });

    $('.thumb_button').colorbox({rel:'photos'});

    if ($('.stockquantity').attr("value") == ''){
        $('.stockquantity').attr("value","0");
    }

});
</script>
```

in body

```
<div id="image_box">
   <img class="cover" src="/upload/productimage/ca05c9c1e01179087d3c9015a4097ce9-medium.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="thumbnail_box">
   <ul id="mycarousel" class="jcarousel-skin-product">
      <li><a class="thumb_button" href="/upload/productimage/ca05c9c1e01179087d3c9015a4097ce9.jpg" image="/upload/productimage/ca05c9c1e01179087d3c9015a4097ce9.jpg" image-cover="/upload/productimage/ca05c9c1e01179087d3c9015a4097ce9-medium.jpg"><img src="/upload/productimage/ca05c9c1e01179087d3c9015a4097ce9-thumb.jpg" width="66" height="66" alt="" border="0" /></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
<div class="thumbnail_tip center">(Click on thumbnails to enlarge image)</div>       
</div> 
<div class="small-12 medium-12 large-12 columns">    
   <div class="desc">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
   </div>
</div>
<!--only for productdetail.php ends-->
```

Comment: Your website is high risk. What happened?

Comment: The chrome console shows two errors, two instances of "undefined is not a function". The line numbers don't help, though. But that is likely the problem

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. Just need to remove this from footer.

```
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
```